# Looking for the Lost tribes : Are Bantus speaking Ancient Hebrew?

Tags: hebrew, language

On YouTube many videos link the Bantu languages to the ancient Hebrew. Would you know if any scholar ever studied the link between both languages do understand how they influence each other? Could the Bantus be some of the lost tribes of Israel/Judah...?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=VFwdfelR5bE&feature=emb_logo

Zephaniah 3:9 to 3:10
"For then will I turn to the people a pure language, that they may all call upon the name of the LORD, to serve him with one consent.
From beyond the rivers of Ethiopia my suppliants, even the daughter of my dispersed, shall bring mine offering."

Bantus do live beyond the rivers of Cush/Ethipia.

Also, have you ever heard of the Hebrew Israelite movement? Could it be that some of the Bantu tribes and some of the African American are descendant of Israel or Abraham?

Comment: I’m not sure if this is off topic because of at least some kind of reference to actual texts. But the questions posed seem to be predominantly opinion based. I vote to close.

Comment: It should be noted that some of the Bantu languages (such as Swahili) are influenced by Arabic, which in turn is a Semitic language related to Hebrew. So some of the apparent similarities between Bantu and Hebrew may be due to that.

Comment: @Meir Thank you for your reply. Oooh yes you are right. Thats a great point. I didnt think about it before. I am now looking at it on youtube. Some Bantu speaker say that Arabic language derive from Bantu and not the contrary but with not much proof. It gets me even more curious. Its just a fascinating topic. Would you know of any scholar that made academic studies of Arabic, Hebrew and Bantu languages to understand the connection between those languages? and better understand the origin of Hebrew.

Comment: Read Saenz-Badillos' book, and you'll have a quite clear idea from where Hebrew (and Arabic) come from, and you'll see why the cited claim is impossible.

Comment: @Kazibácsi Thank you for your advise. I will read his books

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple of videos discussing the Hebrew Israelite movement's claims from a historial perspective. I have personally debated them at some length and their Biblical arguments are very flimsy, usually referring to a verse describing dark skin. The ironic part is that said verse often mentions skin darkening due to an external cause, showing that the original Jews were not black. While it is theoretically possible that some Jews moved to Africa and became black, there must be concrete evidence in order to consider their claims. And the claim that all African-Americans are descendants of Jews is pure fantasy. (I can clarify more if you are interested.)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HGDsgJrBCk&list=LLgF9GfrjnHGymOQq2kWm2aQ&index=5&t=0s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gOiKl8WsyQ&list=LLgF9GfrjnHGymOQq2kWm2aQ&index=4&t=616s

Comment: Thank you @N.T. Nice videos. He debunked the 18th century map of Ghana that shows "kingdom of Juda". This map alone was pretty convincing for me but now I understand that "Juda" comes from Weda which in the original  language meant house of the serpent. Thanks for those videos.